# Terraform output variables to be used as input variables

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I want to use output variables of one resource/module as an input to another resource/modules. Is that possible? Here i want the output value from 'outputs.tf' in root to be used as input in 'main.tf' of module.

```
    root
    |--main.tf
    |--vars.tf
    |--outputs.tf
    |---module
         |--main.tf
         |--vars.tf
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: This doesnt answer my question

Comment: So what is the issue you meet now? And can you share all the terraform files you use?

Comment: I wanted to use the output variables that are defined in output.tf file as an input to another resource..Is that possible?  @CharlesXu

Comment: Of course yes. Do you read my answer carefully? I showed in it.

Comment: I want to output a password and then use that outputed password as an input in another module. Here as i  see, you have given the value for rg_name in module rg and then referred it in the other module. I cant hardcode the password in the code. I hope you understood my question. @CharlesXu

Comment: I don't understand by just talking. I need the message and code.

Comment: I tried to explain my question by making changes in it. @CharlesXu

Comment: See my update in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. And there is nothing more you need to do. Just do it as usual. Here is an example:

```
main.tf
├── rg
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── rg.tf
└── vnet
    ├── output.tf
    └── vnet.tf
```

You create the modules `rg` and `vnet` as it does. Set the output you need. Here I set the output `rg_name` and `rg_location`. And I also set the variables `rg_name` and `rg_location` in the module `vnet` as need. Then the main.rf shows here:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "rg" {
  source = "./rg"

  rg_name = "charlesTerraform"
}

module "vnet" {
  source = "./vnet"

  rg_name = module.rg.rg_name
  rg_location = module.rg.rg_location
}

output "vnet" {
  value = module.vnet.vnet
}
```

You see, I use the output of the module `rg` as input for the module `vnet`. Hope it help you understand the Terraform modules.

**Update:**

It's also the same way when the structure is the thing you said. You just need to input the output you need into the module. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "xxxxxx"
  location = "xxxx"
}

module "vnet" {
  source = "./modules"

  resource_group = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
```

This is just an example, but it shows you how to achieve it. Hope you understand.

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Hope you will try it soon and give the result.

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Well, you can accept it as the answer when it works for you.

Comment: Did it.! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the terraform output command to interpolate output value to other means as variables.

See this terraform docs https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30663370)